# How to access the text property of a WKInterfaceLabel in Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

I want to type an if statement in the InterfaceController which basically goes like-

```
if label.text == "Hello" {
//execute some code
}
```

But the `WKInterfaceLabel` just seems to have the `setText()` property. So how can I access the `WKInterfaceLabel`'s text property? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First step in answering every problem: google the class you have a problem with. That will always give you a link from apple with all available functions, variables and constants in a class. [WKInterfaceLabel class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Longer answer, store the string in a separate variable and use that for the `if` statements.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var myLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    var myString : String = ""

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        myString = "hello"
        myLabel.setText(myString)

        if myString == "hello" {

            //so awesome stuff here

        }
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```